# No connection string named 'BioStarEntities' could be found in the app.config file

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, user-controls

I'm programming an application with WPF using entity Framework. So, I created a MinWindow with a grid which I can fill with UserControls. For instance, one UserControl has a DataGrid, and this DataGrid is filled by binding with a List (this list is filled from an Entity). The problem is I got this error : No connection string named 'BioStarEntities' could be found in the app.config file. and these lines are underlined :

```
    <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" LastChildFill="True" Grid.Row="1">
        <y:Image x:Name="image" Visibility="Visible"/>
        <y:Pointage_Regularise x:Name="pointageRegularise" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
        <y:PointParDep x:Name="pointageParDep" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
        <y:ListeEmployes x:Name="listeEmployes" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
    </DockPanel>
```

this code is for MainWindow. and Image, Pointage_Regularise, PointParDep, ListeEmployes are the UserControls which I call to this MainWindow. I hope that my question is clear. 
I tried to  add the connection string to the assembly in which I have the main project but no positive result.

This is a code I used to retrieve data from database :

```
public ImageViewModel()
    {
    }
    public List<DataModel.CERTI_PARAMETRAGE> listParam()
    {
                var logoparam = (from DataModel.CERTI_PARAMETRAGE el in SessionContext.DBContext.CERTI_PARAMETRAGE
                        where el.id_parametrage==1
                        select el).ToList();

                return logoparam;
    }
```

Comment: This error is crystal clear. Some component you are using is looking for a connection string and it is not there. You need to add it.

Comment: Put your `app.config` here

Comment: I did what you said but any result, please take another look to my question I added more details

Comment: Could you show us the app.config code in your main project? (if it is too extensive, just the blocks close to your connection string)

Comment: here is it : `<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="BioStarEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ModelBioStar.csdl|res://*/ModelBioStar.ssdl|res://*/ModelBioStar.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\BSServer;initial catalog=BioStar;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>`

Comment: Is the connection string in both the EF and the main projects? (it should)
Is the Entity framework referenced in the main project?

Comment: Yes I have in References: "DataModel" and "EntityFrameWork"

Comment: I think the problem is not in relation with the Assemblies, because I've made all files in one assembly and I still have the problem. the problem cannot be here? `<y:Image x:Name="image" Visibility="Visible"/>
            <y:Pointage_Regularise x:Name="pointageRegularise" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            <y:PointParDep x:Name="pointageParDep" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            <y:ListeEmployes x:Name="listeEmployes" Visibility="Collapsed"/>`. here I tried to call the UserControls I need to the MainWindow window

Answer (score 1):

Well, that kind of error doesn't seem to be related to the presentation layer itself.

This error may occur if the EF is located in a different assembly, so that the connection string is set up there by default when you are using model first, but not in your presentation assembly app.config (which is the application entry point).

I'd suggest to copy the connection string from the EF assembly to the WPF assembly.

I'm guessing that the ListeEmployes or other user control is being populated from database and that is triggering the error.

Comment: I did what you said but any result, please take another look to my question I added more details